# Can't I return an array from a function? C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, return

I'm trying to return an array from a function and to do that a have a pointer in the function but when i try to return the array it returns only the first element! :S

This is my code:

```
int* getDate() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);

    int i;
    static int date[7];//i save in each position the year, month, day, h, m and s

    date[0] = tm.tm_year + 1900;
    date[1] = tm.tm_mon + 1;
    date[2] = tm.tm_mday;
    date[3] = tm.tm_hour;
    date[4] = tm.tm_min;
    date[5] = tm.tm_sec;

    return date;    
}

int main(){
    int *p;
    int i;
    p = getDate();

    for (i = 0; i<6; i++){
        printf("%d/", *p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Desired output: 2014/12/24/3/44/12   (year/month/day/hour/minute/seconds)

Current output: 2014/2014/2014/2014/2014/2014

Comment: Perhaps you meant to print `p[i]` or `*p++`? As written, you print the first element of `p` six times.

Answer (score 2):

make this change.

```
for (i = 0; i<6; i++){
    printf("%d/", p[i]);
```

You have retuned a pointer to the array, pointers can in many ways be used like arrays.

Comment: thank you! so stupid mistake. i thought that being a pointer function must had the pointer :(

Answer (score 1):

use `*(p+i)` in the for loop inside main

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not with the return value it is with your print statement. An array is exactly the same thing in C as a pointer: it's really just a pointer to the first element. You can then just add your index to the pointer before dereferencing to get the correct array item.

Change your print statement to `printf("%d/", *(p + i));`